# QuickFix - 'ObjectDisposedException' error on NewOrderSingle

Tags: c#, quickfix, forex

I'm working on FxPro Ctrader broker (FIX 4.4) and I'm trying to make an FixApi  in C# using QuickFix/n library (1.7.0.0).

> I stucked at 'NewOrderSingle':
>   After successful logon I'm trying to make an order:

```
class TradeConnection : MessageCracker, IApplication
{
  public void OnLogon(SessionID sessionID)
    {  
       Write.Info("Account TRADE successful logged " + sessionID);  
       sendOrder();    
    }

  public void sendOrder()
    {
       NewOrderSingle oc = new NewOrderSingle();
       ClOrdID ID = new ClOrdID("1408479");
       Symbol symb = new Symbol("1");
       Side side = new Side('1');
       OrderQty lots = new OrderQty(1000);
       OrdType type = new OrdType('1');
       TransactTime TransactTime = new TransactTime(DateTime.Now);
       TimeInForce TimeInForce = new TimeInForce('3');
       oc.SetField(ID);
       oc.SetField(symb);
       oc.SetField(side);
       oc.SetField(lots);
       oc.SetField(type);
       oc.SetField(TimeInForce);
       send(oc);
     }

  public void send(QuickFix.Message message)
    {  
      Session.SendToTarget(message, sessionID);      
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't working and I get error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

Same error appears @

> RequestForPositions and OrderStatusRequest

On same account in api that uses NetworkStream rather than QuickFix lib it works fine.

Comment: got a stacktrace?

Comment: it stacks in Quickfix.dll

Comment: at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at QuickFix.SocketInitiatorThread.ReadSome(Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds)

Comment: Is it a problem with identifying sessionID in the send() function?

Comment: Nope, somehow command NewOrderSingle causes that QuickFix doesn't recognise this command and logouts client and disposes session. That's why this DisposedError occurs. Question is: Why QuickFix doesn't fill my cmd request, or at least it should pass cmd to broker and I should get reject info. It looks like send(oc) command causes QuickFix unable to create correct construct message with standard header and trailer

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Forgot to set field TransactTime which counterparty required:

```
oc.SetField(TransactTime);
```